# jqModal and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqmodal

I want to create a simple form for adding new products using *jqModal*.

**View / Home / Index.aspx:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#addProductControlSection').jqm({ modal: true,
                ajax: '<%: Url.Action("AddProduct", "Home") %>',
                onHide: myAddClose
            });

            function myAddClose(hash) {
                hash.w.fadeOut('1000', function () { hash.o.remove(); });
            }

        });
    </script>

    // rest of the code...

<a href="#" class="jqModal">Add product</a>

<div id="addProductControlSection" class="jqmWindow">

</div>
```

**HomeController:**

```
public ActionResult AddProduct()
{
    return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddProduct(Product product)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // how to show an error?
    }

    _productRepository.Save(product);
    // how to display 'success' or something...
}
```

I don't know how to implement validation. If user enters incorrect value for the Product.Price and clicks Save button, I don't want to close the form. I would like to display an error message like the one when using *Validation Summary* on normal views.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) or using [MVC Model Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) to autogenerate the JS. The fact that it's in a modal dialog should have no effect on these techniques.

Comment: When I click Save button on the modal dialog, I enter the if(!ModelState.IsValid) and return View("AddProduct", product) is called. After that, modal dialog is closed and I want to prevent it.

Comment: Regarding submit button... I forgot to include 'MicrosoftAjax.js' and 'MicrosoftMvcAjax.js' scripts.